# Add taxonomy to already registered custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

I want to add taxonomy to already registered custom post type. Is it possible or I have to delete and create that custom post type again??

Comment: Yes, totally possible, no need to create a new cpt

Answer (score 3):

You want to use the register_taxonomy_for_object_type function [documented here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_taxonomy_for_object_type/)

```
add_action('init','fix_my_tax');    
function fix_my_tax(){
    register_taxonomy_for_object_type('taxonomy', 'post_type');
}
```